# See instructions executed by a compiled code?

Tags: instructions, instruction-set

In a laboratory in my University we use a program called IAR that allowed us to see every instruction (in assembler) being executed by a particular code, but in that case we know the code of the program, so I was wondering if exist any tool or method to see the instructions being procesed or the memory being changed by a program in particular, is that possible?

Comment: Could you clarify the question? Do you want to view the current instruction being executed? On a PC or on microcontroller?

Comment: I want to view the instructions on a PC of a program executed in the PC. Thanks for your insterest

Answer (score 0):

The (software) tool you are looking for is called a debugger. It can step through the execution of a program, inspect memory, do register dumps etc. IAR produces commercial debuggers, but others exist too. Microsoft's commercial product, Visual Studio, has a debugger built into it, and on the free/open source side you can use GNU GDB, which is pretty popular and can work on most operating systems:

https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/

For the debugger to be most effective, your code needs to be compiled with debug symbols on, which helps the debugger give you function and variable names if your original source code was written in a high-level language.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi!, thanks for your answer.
I'm aware of the existence of debuggers and I've used sometimes dgb, but i was thinking, something to view the instructions executed and the memory changed by a program already compiled (without "debug symbols on"). It is possible for GDB allow me to see the information stored (and changed) in the memory or view the instructions being executed by a program compiled without debug symbols on?

Comment: Yes, this is possible: use "disassemble" command to view instructions. In TUI mode (https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/TUI-Keys.html#TUI-Keys) disassembly window is also available. As always, you can view memory using "x" command: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Memory.html#Memory